# Did Clear know the mortician personally, before we even see him for the first time?

Tags: final-destination

I can't help but feel a mysteriousness about Clear even in the first *Final Destination* movie...

She says, "Then let's go see him," in such a way, foreshadowing his appearance, as if she knows who the mortician is.

Is there something to this?

Note: I know Clear was referring to Todd when she said that, but it was said in such a foreshadowing way, and the atmosphere was so foreshadowing that it seemed like Clear.